# Turn off email notification - iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

Anyone know a way to disable email notification when app status changes? I have 10+ internal testers and don't want them to be spammed by email whenever app status is changed.

Edit: All users have no territories in for all options Notification Tab.

Comment: @JackKFouani nope, they said this can't be done

Comment: tell them to add filters on their email based on the email title... its always the same title, so at least they can automatically have them moved to a trash folder

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Himanth

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to `TestFlightApp`
2. Select the app which is sending you email notifications
3. Select from the bottom `Notifications`
4. Remove the `Email push notifications`

Comment: I don't have an iOS device, so I don't have access to TestFlightApp. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by setting iTunesConnect -> Users And Roles -> User name -> Notifications -> App Status Reports to "No Territories"

[image: App Status Reports]

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,

Mukund

Comment: This works for myself and other internal testers with iTunesConnect/AppStoreConnect access, but don't think it works for external testers I've added to TestFlight. For them @Eironeia option seems to be the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that removes all the notifications, not specific to one app

Comment: This doesn't even work (anymore) :-(

Comment: Still an issue in App Store Connect. I get lots of email notifications about apps I don't care about. There's no way to only receive notifications for app A. and not app B, app C etc. I could turn this feature off but then I wouldn't get notifications about app A which is the one I'm working on. So what I did for now is use filtering in my email client (gmail) to sort out email notifications about apps I don't work on.